# Deploying Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, installation, windows-installer, inno-setup

I am developing a chained installer including the .msi installation of Crystal Reports Basic (10.5) using Inno Setup.  I cannot find any deployment guidance to determine if this is already installed on the target PC, though it appears I can call the .msi multiple times and it always attempts to install (never goes to the typical repair/remove).

I have found a registry key under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products\ for Crystal Reports and I can also locate an assembly in the GAC.  Being new to Inno Setup, I am not sure how to locate a file in the GAC, but I think I can figure that out.

My question is: Is option either recommended?  Is there a better option than either of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got through the same problem some time ago and there is the solution. Inno script with **Crystal Report Installation**. [Crystal Report 9 and 11 Installation](http://www.sportamok.com/development/delphi/13-inno-setup-crystal-report-deployment)

I like Inno since it's fast, easy and you have full control over the whole process. Crystal Report msi package is just pain.

Hope It helps.

Comment: It is a real shame that you had to roll your own solution to this problem.  Surprising that for something bundled into Visual Studio it goes against standard Microsoft installation guidelines since merge modules are no longer recommended.

Answer (score 1):

When we were using Crystal, we used the merge modules. We were also using the setup and deployment projects in visual studio, so there was an option to detect whether or not it was already installed.

Have you seen this? http://www.randem.com/crsupport.html